# What does the notation $E^{(k)}$ mean in this proof of Bool’s inequality?

Tags: notation

I'm reading through some notes which give a proof by induction for Bool's inequality, and  I wondered if someone could explain what the notation. I'm confused by the $E^{(k)}$, what does this mean?
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr\left[\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} E_i\right]
&= \Pr\left[E^{(k)} \cup E_{k+1}\right] \\
&\leq \Pr[E^{(k)}] + \Pr[E^{(k+1)}] \\[4pt]
&\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \Pr[E_i]\right) + \Pr[E_{k+1}] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \Pr[E_i].
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the formula you linked to, it means $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^k E_k$.

This is not really a standard bit of notation, so I hope it is explained before it is used.

Comment: Thank you, do the brackets around the k have any meaning? Is it that which implies the union?

Comment: It could well be at an early part of the notes, I'm only taking reading through a few pages from this source. Thank you very much

Comment: The brackets are to distinguish it from $E^k$, which has a pretty standard meaning of direct product $E\times E\times\cdots\times E$, as in $\mathbb{R}^3$.